# duda en FREETEXTTABLE y su KEY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy usando FREETEXTTABLE sin embargo cuando trato de hacer el inner join el resultado me queda vacio no mostrandome nada al final aunque no me marca error tampoco, simplemente me marca todo como vacio

```
SELECT * FROM FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.tabla1,*,'algo') AS T INNER JOIN 
dbo.tabla2 AS U ON T.[KEY] = U.id;
```

Tengo la sospecha que es en el FULL TEXT INDEX pero me gustaria recibir su consejo antes de mover algo mas, si necesitan mas información por favor diganme

Comment: ¿Has probabo haciendo la consulta a `FREETEXTTABLE` sin el join para ver si obtienes algún resutlado?

Comment: De alguna forma siempre me marca error, no se en que puede que este fallando

Comment: ¿De qué error estás hablando? En tu pregunta dices que no hay error, sino que queda vacío. Si tienes mas inforamción, compártela.